# Memory overflow when running scrapy from script

Tags: python, memory, scrapy

I have written a spider in scrapy to crawler hundreds of thousands of pages from some news webistes. It works well when I start it from command line tools and the memory usage reach a stable level of 20% on my 4GB PC. (I have used priority on requests to ensure there won't be tooo many requests alive.) But when I start it from a python script , the usage of memory continue to grow until my spider eat up all the memory space. This is my start-up script:

```
class CrawlersInitiator(object):

    def __init__(self, spiders, start=datetime.now()-timedelta(minutes=30), end=datetime.now()):
        self.setting = get_project_settings()
        self.crawlers = []
        self.spiders = spiders
        self.start_time = start
        self.end_time = end
        # log file
        self.info_log = None
        log_dir = self.setting.get("LOG_DIR")
        if not os.path.exists(log_dir):
            os.mkdir(log_dir)
        # counter used to stop reactor
        self.stopped_crawler = 0
        self.lock = RLock()

    def __del__(self):
        self.close_log_file()

    def create_log_file(self):
    """ create log file with crawl date in file name
    """
        self.close_log_file()
        dir_path = self.setting.get("LOG_DIR")+"/{0}".format(self.end_time.strftime("%Y-%m"))
        file_suffix = self.end_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        if not os.path.exists(dir_path):
            os.mkdir(dir_path)
        self.info_log = open("{0}/log-{1}.log".format(dir_path, file_suffix), "a")  # info

    def close_log_file(self):
        if self.info_log and not self.info_log.closed:
            self.info_log.close()
            self.info_log = None

    def get_crawler(self, spider):
        crawler = Crawler(self.setting)
        crawler.signals.connect(self.stop, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        crawler.configure()
        crawler.crawl(spider(start_time=self.start_time, end_time=self.end_time))
        return crawler

    def stop(self):
        """callback to stop reactor
        """
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.stopped_crawler += 1
        if self.stopped_crawler >= len(self.crawlers):
            reactor.stop()
        self.lock.release()

    def run_spiders(self):
        """run spiders
        """
        self.crawlers = []
        self.stopped_crawler = 0
        # get crawlers
        for Spider in self.spiders:
            self.crawlers.append(self.get_crawler(Spider))
        # log
        self.create_log_file()
        ScrapyFileLogObserver(self.info_log, level=log.INFO).start() 
        self.info_log.write("\nCrawlers starting...\n")
        self.info_log.write("Crawl from {0} to {1}".format(str(self.start_time), str(self.end_time)))

        # run
        for crawler in self.crawlers:
            crawler.start()
        reactor.run()
        end = datetime.now()

        # release crawlers
        for crawler in self.crawlers:
            del crawler

        # log
        self.info_log.write("Crawlers finished in {0} !\n".format(str(end-self.end_time)))
        self.close_log_file()


def crawl(spiders, start, end):
    CrawlersInitiator(spiders, start=start, end=end).run_spiders()

SPIDERS = [MySpider1, MySpider2]    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = datetime.strptime(sys.argv[1], "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")
    end_time = datetime.strptime(sys.argv[2], "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S")          
    crawl(SPIDERS, start_time, end_time)            
    quit()
```

I have tried to use scrapy trackref to find the problem.

When start from command line tools, the prefs() shows(Only one spider started):

```
MySpider1                           1   oldest: 942s ago
HtmlResponse                       13   oldest: 52s ago
Request                          6329   oldest: 932s ago
Item                             5915   oldest: 932s ago
Selector                           13   oldest: 52s ago
```

When start from script, the prefs() shows：

```
Response                           51   oldest: 657s ago 
Request                          6966   oldest: 661s ago 
Item                             5732   oldest: 661s ago 
HtmlResponse                      377   oldest: 661s ago 
Selector                          377   oldest: 661s ago 
MySpider1                           1   oldest: 661s ago
```

It looks like scrapy never release any objects when strated from my script. Why this happen and how to solve it?

Here is the superclass of the all my spiders, all of the requests are processed in this class:

```
class IndexSpider(Spider):

    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta  

    # splice _queries onto _search_url to get start_requests (index pages of news)
    _search_url = ""
    _queries = []

    _char_set = "utf8"

    def __init__(self, queries=self._queries, start_time=datetime.min, end_time=datetime.now()):        
        self.queries = queries
        self.start_time = start_time
        self.end_time = end_time

    def start_requests(self):
        query_count = 0
        query = None
        try:
            for query in self.queries:
                yield Request(self._search_url.format(urllib.quote(query.encode(self._char_set))), self.parse_index)
                query_count += 1
        except Exception, e:
            self.log("Query No.{0} can't be encoded in {1}, because of {2}!"
                     .format(str(query_count), self.name, e), level=log.WARNING)
            yield Request(self._search_url.format(query.encode("gbk")), self.parse_index)

    def parse_index(self, response):
        """parse index page
        """
        requests = []
        page_list = self._get_result(response)

        if not page_list:
            return requests
        next_page = True  

        for item in page_list:
            if isinstance(item, Request):  
                requests.append(item)
                next_page = False
                break
            if item['publish_time'] <= self.from_time: 
                next_page = False
                break
            elif item['publish_time'] > self.end_time:
                continue
            else:
                req = Request(item['url'], self.parse_news, priority=1)
                req.meta["item"] = item
                requests.append(req)
        if next_page:
            next_page = self._next_index_page(response)
            if next_page:
                requests.append(Request(self._next_index_page(response), self.parse_index))
        return requests

    def parse_news(self, response): 
        """parse news page
        """
        item = response.meta["item"]
        del response.meta['item']
        return self._finish_item(item, response)

    @abstractmethod
    def _get_result(self, response):
        """get news list from index page
        :param response: index page
        :return: a list of objects of crawlers.items.Base or its subclass, each object represents a news
        """
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def _next_index_page(self, response):
        """
        :param response: current index page
        :return: URL of the next index page
        """
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def _finish_item(self, item, response):
        """parse news page
        :param item: news item get from the index page
        :param response: news page
        :return: news item or new request
        """
        pass
```

Comment: Hi! Would you be able to paste the code for your spiders too? Mostly this arises since the scrapy scheduler still has the Request object in its memory which could either be switching between `yield`ing a Request or `return`ing a request. If you want to checkout a basic implementation for running multiple spiders, I have a blog [here](http://kirankoduru.github.io/)  that can help you.

Comment: @kiran.koduru I have post the superclass of all my spiders, in which all of the requests are created and processed.

Comment: Are you still working on this issue ? Can you post the `prefs()` after running for atleast 5-10 mins?

Comment: @kiran.koduru Sorry for repling so late! The prefs()s I have post are both running for longer than 10mins. And my spiders crash after running for 20-30mins. It looks like scrapy haven't recycled any objects when started from scripts. I doubt whether I have something wrong with twisted...

Answer (score 2):

maybe scrapy isn't using the whole power of your computer when running from a script. You could still use Settings to control the spider behaviour:

```
my_settings = {
    'MEMUSAGE_ENABLED' = 1,
    'MEMUSAGE_LIMIT_MB' = 1024,
    'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS' = 100 # lower this if it is still reaching memory limits
}
process = CrawlerProcess(my_settings) 

process.crawl(MySpider)
process.start()
```